# Basic topological space proof

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> $T = \{(-n,n):n\in{\rm I\!R}\backslash\{\pm\infty\}\}$
>
> Show that $T$ is not a topology on ${\rm I\!R}$.

The question was that (-n,n) is bounded. My professor said both (1) "$\phi,X\in T$" and (2) "The arbitrary union is in $T$" fail.
I found (1) since (-n,n) is bounded. But I don't know why (2) fails. I thought the arbitrary union of intervals of the form (-n,n) is the largest interval in $T$.

Comment: What if there is no largest interval in the union?

Comment: $(-n-1,n+1)$ is larger :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $G_n = (-n,n), n\in \mathbf Z^+$.  Then $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}{G_n}=(-\infty, \infty)\notin T$$

That is, $T$ is not closed under arbitrary unions.

Comment: Since (-n,n) is bounded interval, (−∞,∞) is not in T. And each G_n is in T but how did you get the union of G_n is (−∞,∞)?

Comment: @Anthony Every element of $\mathbf R$ is in one of those intervals, isn't it?

Comment: Isn't the largest element of R not in the interval?

Comment: @Anthony There is no largest element of $\mathbf R$.  If $x$ is the largest element, what about $x+1$?

Comment: I think I understood little bit. The intervals of the form (-n,n) become larger as n increases. And I think the union of the intervals is the largest interval among them. For example the union of (-2,2) and (-1,1) is (-2,2). So I think the union should be the largest interval in T. Could you explain this?

Comment: There doesn't have to be a largest one.  Look at my example.  It has an interval of the form $(-n,n)$ for **every** integer $n$.  What do you think is the largest integer?

Comment: As you said, there's no such integer. I cannot define the number but a number really closest to infinity will not be in T since (-n,n) is bounded. Then how do you include the number in the union?

Comment: I think I got it. If a number closest to infinity is "k", then as you said "k+1" exists, so we cannot define the number "k". So the union is (−∞,∞)

Answer (score 3):

$\varnothing$ is actually in $T$ because the set
$$(-0,0) = \{x \in \Bbb{R} : 0 < x < 0\}$$
is clearly empty. Still, $X = \Bbb{R}$ is not in $T$ because $\Bbb{R}$ is not bounded, while such is every set of $T$.

$T$ is also not closed for arbitrary infinite unions:
$$
A = \bigcup_{n \in \Bbb{N}} (-n, n) \not\in T. 
$$
If you added $\Bbb{R}$ to $T$, then that would turn it into a topology.

Comment: $T$ is **not** closed under arbitrary unions.

Comment: @saulspatz Ops, correct. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: Could you explain more why the union of (-n,n) is not in T?

Comment: That union is the whole real líne, which is not in T (to see this, observe that every real x is smaller than ceil(x) \in N)

Comment: Why is the whole real line not in T?

Comment: That's written in the answer.

Comment: Even adding $\mathbb{R}$ won’t make this a $T_1$ topology, so certainly not the usual topology.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Then what should I add to make it a topology?

Comment: @Anthony the reals is enough I think. But, as I said, it’s not the standard topology as you claimed.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ok. Thanks